# Password regex to block square brackets and space?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Hi I am having a password regex where it allows special characters , numbers and alphabets. But i need to block the `space` and `[ ]` this two square brackets into it. Here i am sharing the regex of what i have done.

`/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-/(/)]).{8,20}$/`

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude a space `[` and `]` you could change the dot to a character class matching non whitespace chars excluding the square brackets.

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[#?!@$%^&*/(/)-])[^[\]\s]{8,20}$
                                                        ^^^^^^^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qerlpq/1)

You might also change the `.*` in the assertions to a negated character class `[^` instead, making use of the [contrast principle](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=\D*[0-9])(?=[^#?!@$%^&*/()-]*[#?!@$%^&*/()-])[^\s\]\[]{8,20}$
```

Note to either escape the hyphen in the character class or place it at the beginning or at the end.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RHXv6h/1)